# Find in terms of f and g, the projection of h upon S, where S = span{f,g}

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-series, inner-products

[image]

My attempt so far is:

ai) $\operatorname{Proj}_S(x)= Px$, where $P = (w_1w_1^T+w_2w_2^T)$ and $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_m\}$ is an orthogonal basis for $S$.

Let $w_1 = f$ and $w_2 = g-\operatorname{proj}_f(g) = g$

It follows that $\operatorname{Proj}_S(x) = (ff^T+gg^T)(x)$

aii) $u_1 = f$

$u_2 = g - \operatorname{proj}_f(g) = g$

$u_3 = h - \operatorname{proj}_f(h) - \operatorname{proj}_g(h)$ = h - $\frac{8f}{|f|^2} - \frac{3g}{|g|^2}$

b) I am unsure how to start this question!

Comment: The fact that the inner project of $f$ and $g$ is $0$ means you can just find the projections onto the spaces spanned by those elements _separately_ and then add the two.